# auto-conversion from struct to long in liinux C++?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm converting a C++ Linux program (I don't know what compiler) to Visual C++ 2019. I'm seeing some strange code.

Today's example is:

```
long offset = timezone;
```

I also see:

```
offset = timezone - 3600;
```

`timezone` appears to be defined as:

```
struct timezone;
```

It should be defined as:

```
struct timezone {
   int tz_minutewest;
   int tz_dsttime;
};
```

I don't see any evidence that it is.

It appears that the code is using `timezone` as if it is `timezone.tz_minutewest`.

Do some compilers do an automatic conversion?

Comment: In vs right click on timezone and do 'go to definition'

Comment: Using a debugger, it should be very easy to inspect type and values under Linux and see what it does...

Comment: All that code shows is that `timezone` is a variable (or define). You have to show where it is defined so the type becomes clear. Maybe someone defined `int timezone = 0; // time offset in seconds from GMT`

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh or something... but... if you stumble across such easy "problems", you probably do not know how to handle either the windows nor the linux side well. You simply lack too much experience for the job at hand. Its more tricky, because you need to find your way around in both systems and probably not a good task to get "your fingers wet" with c++.

Comment: In answer to a couple of questions. 1. If the code doesn';t compile, I can't look at it in the debugger. 2. I did look at the definition. I posted it. 3. I don't know linux at all, but I know C++ very very well. I am trying to modify old linux code to build with a modern visual studio for windows. The code doesn't compile under visual studio. It used to compile under some linux compiler. The code doesn't make sense. Hence me posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `struct timezone` you are showing is a Linux/glibc-specific type defined in `<sys/time.h>`. See [`man gettimeofday`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html).

There is also a variable named `timezone` in `<time.h>` which is specified by POSIX (X/Open). See [`man tzset`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tzset.3.html) for information about the Linux/glibc implementation of that feature.

Of course it is not clear whether you are referring to either of these or something else entirely. However in context where the name is used in your example it cannot name a type.

Even if you have both headers included, using `timezone` in an expression will refer to the variable, not the type. C++ allows collision between the name of a type and a non-type. In most contexts the non-type will be preferred if not explicitly prefixed with `struct` or similar keywords.

Comment: I suspect that this is the right answer. There must be conflicting definitions of timezone and the old linux compiler defaulted to one of the definitions while the visual studio compiler defaults to the other one. both <sys/time.h> and <time.h> are included in this file.

Comment: Microsoft changed the name of timezone to avoid the conflict. The name that they use is _timezone

Answer (score 2):

No C++ compiler should do an automatic conversion from a struct to a long.  If one does, it's buggy.  (But more likely it's just that the code is buggy, or perhaps someone is playing games with `#define` or `typedef` somewhere to change the definition of `timezone` in an unexpected way)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkwJt.png)

Now try the code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct timezone {
    int tz_minutewest;
    int tz_dsttime;
};
int main()
{
    timezone s;
    s.tz_dsttime = 0; //by using s we can access the data members of struct
    int offset = s.tz_minutewest;
    //  int offset = s.tz_dsttime;     //  this is way to call the struct 
    //  by this method you call the data member of structure 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can run this code in VS by this method.

```cpp
struct timezone {
   int tz_minutewest;
   int tz_dsttime;
};
int main()
{
    int offset = timezone.tz_minutewest;
//  int offset = timezone.tz_dsttime;       this is way to call the struct 
//  by this method you call the data member of structure 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not compile and doesn't answer the question.